# Passing custom value to payPal/Cordova plugin through Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cordova, paypal

I am trying to add payPal plugin to my cordova/Angularjs app. Everything works well when i test it with predefined values. However it fails when i try to pass my own custom value to it.

Please how do i pass value/data to the makePayment() or createPayment() Method in Angularjs.
When i Do `Wallet.makePayment($scope.MMParams);` in the controller
I get "cannot get property value of undefined."

```
 .factory('Wallet', function ($q, $ionicPlatform, $window) {
    var service = {
        initPaymentUI: initPaymentUI,
        onSuccesfulPayment: onSuccesfulPayment,
        onFuturePaymentAuthorization: onFuturePaymentAuthorization,
        createPayment: createPayment,
        configuration: configuration,
        onPrepareRender: onPrepareRender,
        onPayPalMobileInit: onPayPalMobileInit,
        onUserCanceled: onUserCanceled,
        makePayment: makePayment
    };


    function initPaymentUI() {
        var clientIDs = {
            "PayPalEnvironmentProduction": "YOUR_PRODUCTION_CLIENT_ID",
            "PayPalEnvironmentSandbox": "YOUR_SANDBOX_CLIENT_ID"
        };
        PayPalMobile.init(clientIDs, onPayPalMobileInit());

    }

    function onSuccesfulPayment(payment) {
        console.log("payment success: " + JSON.stringify(payment, null, 4));
    }

    function onFuturePaymentAuthorization(authorization) {
        console.log("authorization: " + JSON.stringify(authorization, null, 4));
    }
    function createPayment() {
        // for simplicity use predefined amount
        var paymentDetails = new PayPalPaymentDetails("1.50", "0.40", "0.05");
        var payment = new PayPalPayment("1.95", "USD", "Awesome Sauce", "Sale", paymentDetails);
        return payment;
    }
    function configuration() {
        // for more options see `paypal-mobile-js-helper.js`
        var config = new PayPalConfiguration({merchantName: "My Test Shop", merchantPrivacyPolicyURL: "https://mytestshop.com/policy", merchantUserAgreementURL: "https://mytestshop.com/agreement"});
        return config;
    }
    function onPayPalMobileInit() {
        // must be called
        // use PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork mode to get look and feel of the flow
        PayPalMobile.prepareToRender("PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork", configuration(), onPrepareRender());
    }
    function onUserCanceled(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
    function onPrepareRender() {}

    function makePayment() {
        PayPalMobile.renderSinglePaymentUI(createPayment(), onSuccesfulPayment(), onUserCanceled());
    }

    return service;
});
```

I will be glad if someone can help, thank you.

Comment: Is the error actually coming from your own code? What if you remove the parenthesis from the 2nd and 3rd arguments? So just `...onSuccessfulPayment, onUserCanceled);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the function as callback, since renderSinglePaymentUI calls it by himself but you are calling it and passing the return value.

```
function makePayment() {
    PayPalMobile.renderSinglePaymentUI(createPayment(), onSuccesfulPayment(), onUserCanceled());
}
```

should be

```
function makePayment() {
    PayPalMobile.renderSinglePaymentUI(createPayment(), onSuccesfulPayment, onUserCanceled);
}
```

maybe this solves your problem already